# Where can I find information on interfacing an MCU with an HDMI display?

Tags: design, hardware, hdmi, reference-materials

I am just starting the process of creating a product that will have an HDMI display (not chosen), but I don't quite know where to start. I have never delved into the realm of Displays, and don't know where to look in terms of what MCU to choose, what supporting electronics I would need, etc. If someone could point me the the right direction/ offer some insight on their experience with the process, that would be great.

I am starting from ground 0, with nothing yet but an idea.

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to connect an MCU to HDMI display, because you want to see a picture, or some other reason? Basically are you asking what to buy?

Comment: I think it's beyond your capability for now. You can't just jump into something like that without some smaller progressive steps. HDMI tends to be in the realm of processors and not MCUs. What you want to display on the HDMI display also matters. Simple still image UI is very different from say...4K.

Comment: I am wanting to make an HMI that will communicate over Bluetooth to a sensor, but have no idea how to interface an MCU to an HDMI display. I have some experience with PIC chips, but have no idea if those even come close to being powerful enough to drive a display

Comment: There are many PICs 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32-bit. You would need a 32-bit MCU to have any chance of driving an HDMI display, and a high end one of that. Does the display need to be HDMI? Can the display be proprietary? That would ease things a lot since you can use an LCD with a graphics driver and firmware already installed and you just have to send it serial commands for what to draw on screen. But if you want to plug into any monitor you're stuck with HDMI or VGA (if it is still available).

Comment: @DKNguyen not necessarily, but it seems to be the most readily available/ cheap for displays

Comment: What kind of data do you want to display? What resolution and size, and how dynamic does the displayed data need to be? What about SPI or I2C attached displays, which are much easier to interface with MCUs and a lot cheaper than HDMI attached displays.

Comment: All I would need is to display still images that would end up being refreshed with data periodically, and be touch-enabled for the user to switch between windows/tabs to control range variables/ bluetooth devices

Comment: @JamesS Most monitors with HDMI are not touch enabled. If they are, they are expensive. Most likely HDMI is not the technology you want for touch-enabled display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reference design, check out [this link to an Arduino compatible shield and library](https://github.com/techtoys/HDMI-Shield/tree/master/Ra8876_Lite). There it shows the schematics and what chips they used for the MCU (ARM cortex M0+ and ESP32 MCUs) as well as the display drivers (RA8876 TFT controller and CH7035B HDMI encoder).

There are examples there too to help you figure out where to get started.